# How to generate a UUID in Elasticsearch reindex painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to use the reindex api to create a copy of a set of documents. One of the fields (`uuid`) of the document is a UUID. I need the copied documents to have new UUIDs for the `uuid` field.

According to [1] and [2] the method `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` is not whitelisted for use in painless scripts.

*Questions:*

1) How can I generate a UUID in painless?

2) Why is `UUID.randomUUID()` considered an unsafe operation? Or is it just an oversight that it is not whitelisted?

3) How can I whitelist `UUID.randomUUID()` in the `"reindex"` context? I tried to build my own elasticsearch painless extension/plugin to do this based on the example in [3]. The problem is it only works for the `"SearchScript"` context. There does not seem to be an equivalent `"ReindexContext"`.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "index": "product1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "product2"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
'
```

Which produces the following error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "... rce.uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()",
          "                             ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "ctx._source.uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()",
        "lang" : "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "script_exception",
    "reason" : "compile error",
    "script_stack" : [
      "... rce.uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()",
      "                             ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script" : "ctx._source.uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()",
    "lang" : "painless",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "method [java.util.UUID, randomUUID/0] not found"
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

I know my approach is valid and that the above is a painless whitelisting issue because when I try a different method (`fromString()`) I get no errors:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "index": "product1"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "product2"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.uuid = java.util.UUID.fromString(\u0027ad139caa-5b54-4179-b812-5015daecad1e\u0027).toString()",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
'
```

---

*References:*

[1] - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/generate-a-uuid-using-randomuuid-in-painless/144354/3

[2] - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.6/painless-api-reference.html

[3] - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/v6.6.0/plugins/examples/painless-whitelist

*Other Notes:*

- Elasticsearch 6.6
- I've already asked this question on the elasticsearch forum here (no responses):
  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/need-to-generate-uuid-in-painless-script/165318
- I've also asked about whitelisting the `UUID.randomUUID()` method here (no responses):
  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/question-about-painless-whitelist/165523

Comment: May be define your own custom implementation/method in the script to generate uuid's as per your requiremen and use that method. Basically, work around the dependency

Comment: My feature request to resolve this issue has been accepted and implemented here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/39080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My feature request to resolve this issue has been accepted and implemented here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/39080

Answer (score 0):

```
You can simply do the following,

curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "index": "product1"`enter code here`
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "product2"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._id=ctx._id+1",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
'
ctx._id = will always give you a new id and plus 1 will generate the new one.
```

this is just a solution to get unique id by adding suffix

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the question is about updating a uuid field and the outcome needs to be a valid uuid.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is to use a self-written function, here is mine. Of course it is just a workaround but it should help in most cases.

```
String generateUUID(boolean addDashes, boolean upperCase) {
    def chars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

    def dashIndices = [7, 11, 15, 19];

    def sb = new StringBuilder();

    def r = new Random();

    for (def pos = 0; pos < 32; pos += 1) {
       sb.append(chars[r.nextInt(16)]);

       if (addDashes && dashIndices.contains(pos)) {
         sb.append('-');
       }
    }

    def result = sb.toString();

    return upperCase ? result.toUpperCase() : result;
}
```

Copy it to your script and below you will be able to get UUID by calling, for example, `generateUUID(true, false)`, if you need UUID with dashes and in lower case.

Comment: My feature request to resolve this issue has been accepted and implemented here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/39080

Comment: @OliverHenlich Great job! It's good to know Painless will become a bit less painful in the nearest future.

Comment: If you do generate your own random UUID like this, be sure to set the appropriate bits to flag it as a `random` UUID. See: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122 section 4.4.